# `Maximize` does not return any result, but simply reproduce the code

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm working with `Maximize` and it does not generate any result but simply reproduces the same code. My object function is rather complex which is:

$0.18 k-0.36 + \frac{k^2 r (c (0.018\, -0.036 q)+0.0036)+c (-0.02304 q-0.03456)+0.07632}{r}+0.06 (-2 + k) (-5.92 + (-4 + (2 - 0.1 k) k) r + 
   c (0.96 - 0.5 k^2 r + q (0.64 + k^2 r)))$

I would like to find the optimal $r\in [0,1]$ and $k\in [0,1]$ given $q\in [1,2]$ and $c\in [0,1]$. My Mathematica code is as follows:

```
Maximize[{-0.36 + 0.18 k + (0.07632 + c (-0.03456 - 0.02304 q) + k^2 (0.0036 + c (0.018 - 0.036 q)) r)/r + 0.06 (-2. + k) (-5.92 + (-4. + (2. - 0.1 k) k) r + c (0.96 - 0.5 k^2 r + q (0.64 + k^2 r))), 1<=q <=2, 0 <= c <= 1}, {r, k}]
```

Can any one help?

Comment: There is no maximum. If $c=k=0,q=1$ then the value is unbounded as $r\to 0^+$ because of dividing by $r$. More precisely, the value is $0.07632/r + 0.3504 + 0.48r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it exact input:

```
Maximize[
 Rationalize[
  Rationalize@{-0.36 + 
     0.18 k + (0.07632 + c (-0.03456 - 0.02304 q) + 
        k^2 (0.0036 + c (0.018 - 0.036 q)) r)/r + 
     0.06 (-2. + k) (-5.92 + (-4. + (2. - 0.1 k) k) r + 
        c (0.96 - 0.5 k^2 r + q (0.64 + k^2 r))), {1 <= q <= 2, 
     0 <= c <= 1}},
  0], {r, k}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks! May I ask some questions? (i) Why do we have 0 right before {r,k}? (ii) Does the result mean the objective function is negative infinite under the given conditions and, otherwise, positive infinite, regardless of the value of r and k?

Comment: @ppp (i) `Rationalize[expr]` vs. `Rationalize[expr, 0]`; The ifirst is done, and if some numbers did not get rationalized, the second one will force the numbers to be converted to the exact fraction equivalent to the floating-point number, very likely with the large denominator that can make the symbolic solution more difficult to compute.  (In fact, after testing, the second, outer `Rationalize` with the `0` turns out to be unnecessary.)  (ii) The answer means the function is unbounded, probably because of the `r` in the denominator.